# draw circle with varying stroke weight

Tags: processing, p5.js

how would a go about drawing the inner blue slice of this circle, to simulate varying stroke weight.

[image]

I have tried a approach where i draw the stroke by drawing small circles on each angle of the circle and increasing the radius on certain parts of the circle. But this doesnt give the right result because the circle gets "pixelated" in the edge, and it skews the circle outwards.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to accomplish this. Part of the difficulty is that Canvas, the underlying technology that p5.js uses to draw graphics, doesn't support variable stroke weights either. In Scalable Vector Graphics, which has similar limitations, the best way to accomplish this would be to describe the shape as the outer perimeter, and the perimeter of the inner void, and then fill the shape without any stroke. I think Canvas would support this approach, but I don't think it can be done easily with p5.js because there's now way to jump to a new position when drawing bezier curves with `beginShape()`/`bezierVertex()`. However, one way you could do this in p5.js would be to fill the outer shape and then "remove" the inner void. If you want to draw this on top of other existing graphics then the best way is to draw this shape to a separate `p5.Graphics` object which you then draw to your main canvas with `image()`:

```js
let sprite;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  sprite = createGraphics(100, 100);
  sprite.noStroke();
  sprite.fill('black');
  sprite.angleMode(DEGREES);
  sprite.circle(50, 50, 100);
  // switch to removing elements from the graphics
  sprite.erase();
  // Translate and rotate to match the shape you showed in your question
  sprite.translate(50, 50);
  sprite.rotate(-45);
  // Remove a perfect semi circle from one half, producing regular 5px stroke circle
  sprite.arc(0, 0, 90, 90, -90, 90);
  // Remove a half-ellipse from the other side of the circle, but this time the
  // height matches the previous arc, but the width is narrower.
  // Note: the angles for this arc overlap the previous removal by a few degrees
  // to prevent there from being a visible seam in between the two removed shapes.
  sprite.arc(0, 0, 70, 90, 85, 275, OPEN);
}

function draw() {
  background('lightgray');
  image(sprite, mouseX - 50, mouseY - 50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: @MadsLeeJensen today I discovered https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/beginContour which should also be usable to solve this problem by subtracting the inner shape from the outer shape thus making an outline, however you would have to compute the appropriate bezier curve points for each of the arcs.